# string matches the pattern using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm using following code to check the string matches the pattern using regex. For the `ptr2` shouldn't matches the pattern but result has matches. What is wrong?

```
ptr1="ptreee765885"
ptr2="hdjfhdjh@@@@"
str1=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+')

result=str1.match(ptr1)
result1=str1.match(ptr2)

if str1.match(ptr2):
print (" string matches %s",ptr2)
else:
print (" string not matches pattern %s",ptr2)
```

Comment: Both will match expectedly..whats your goal?

Comment: Both strings have sequences of alphanumerics, which is all you are testing for.

Comment: have you tried using a debug function?

Comment: how to check for the string having '- ',',' whitspace and |

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the $ to match the end of the string:

```
str1=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
```

You should also include the ^ character at the beginning to match the beginning of the string if you need the entire string to match:

```
str1=re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
```

That will only match if the entire string matches that selection.

Answer (score 0):

Python [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is not the same as `regex_match` in C++ std::regex or Java `String#matches` method, it only searches for a match at the *start* of the string.

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

Thus, to fail a match with your `ptr2`, the **regex should only have a `$` (or `\Z`) anchor at the end if you are using `re.match`**:

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/m7pBUi):

```
import re
ptr2="hdjfhdjh@@@@"
str1=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
if str1.match(ptr2):
   print (" string matches %s",ptr2)
else:
   print (" string not matches pattern %s",ptr2)
# => (' string not matches pattern %s', 'hdjfhdjh@@@@')
```

If you plan to use **[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), you need both `^` and `$` anchors to require a *full string match***:

```
import re
ptr2="hdjfhdjh@@@@"
str1=re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$')
if str1.search(ptr2):
   print (" string matches %s",ptr2)
else:
   print (" string not matches pattern %s",ptr2)
```

[Another demo](http://ideone.com/7axxTK)